# SOLR: No cores available

Tags: java, solr

Trying to connect to my local solr server 5.4.0 via java

```
public class Test {
public static void main(String[] args) throws SolrServerException, IOException{

//  ArrayList<String> sellers = Util.readFile("sellersBP.csv", true);

    SolrClient solr = new HttpSolrClient("http://localhost:8983/solr/#/techproducts/");
     QueryResponse resp = solr.query("techproducts",new SolrQuery("*:*"));

}
}
```

However I get an error message with a bunch of HTML tags and in it says.
     `Exception in thread "main" org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrClient$RemoteSolrException: Error from server at http://localhost:8983/solr/#/techproducts: Expected mime type application/octet-stream but got text/html.`

No cores available
              Go and create one

This is odd because i am using the sample solr example and it created a core in my UI called techproducts. Any advice?

[image: Solr UI]

URL

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The URL `http://localhost:8983/solr/#/techproducts/` has the local anchor (everything behind `#`) present, which is only available to the browser itself (it's never sent to the server). This is used by the JavaScript in the Admin UI to retrieve information from the correct core.

The *actual* URL used to access the core would be `http://localhost:8983/solr/techproducts/`

Comment: I swapped it out for your URL but now I get a 404 not found returned back

Comment: Which seems to indicate that you're actually querying an empty server - are you sure you're using the same URL both places? (matching port numbers, etc) Is localhost the same in both examples?

Comment: I added an extra screenshot (lasts on page) that shows the port number for local host under URL

Comment: Try: http://localhost:8983/solr as your url. You're specifying the collection in `solr.query("techproducts",new SolrQuery("*:*"));`